# Sendgrid issue with port in url

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email from sendgrid using their templates.  In my template I have `<a href="-link-">Click here</a>` and then in my nodeJs code I use this   mail.addSubstitution('-link-', href).  That works fine for basic href's, but if I try to make the href with a port in it (ex. www.my-test-site.com:3333) it removes the href completely.  Same thing if the href is for localhost. I am using sendgrid from a node api

Comment: This was as simple as having http:// in the link.  Without it, it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the colon with double backslash colon \\: to escape the character.  If you post your submit code we can give a better idea of where to place/replace the escape character.  Basically, just before you have your `mail.addSubstitution('-link-', href)` line, do a simple find/replace such as `href.replace(/:/g,"\\\\:");`